# divide and insert with precision oracle

Tags: oracle, numbers, precision

I need insert one record in table with precision in query. For example:

```
insert into spend_amount (record_no,purchase_amount) 
values ('1',(to_number(100.99/2)));
```

I have a purchase_amount column as VARCHAR2. So that when executing this query it inserted as `50.495`. But I need to insert two places of precision only. Expected result should be `50.49` or should round up as `50.50`. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle SQL includes a `round()` function. The first parameter is the value, the second controls the degree of rounding. So to round to two decimal places: `round((100.99/2),2)`.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions169.htm#SQLRF00698).

Not sure why you have a `to_number()` call in your sample code, as what you already have *is* a number. Also, it's a really bad idea to store numeric values as strings: it's a lifetime of needless pain.

Answer (score 1):

First, it makes no sense to store a numeric value like `purchase_amount` as a `varchar2`.  It really, really, really ought to be stored as a number in which case it will actually have whatever precision you specify automatically.

Second, it does not make sense to call `to_number` on a numeric value.  `to_number` only accepts a string.  So if you pass in a numeric value, Oracle has to implicitly cast the number to a string, then `to_number` explicitly casts the string back to a number just to get you right back to where you started.

If you want the value to be rounded to 50.5, use `round`.  If you want the value to be truncated to 50.49, use `trunc`.

```
insert into spend_amount( record_no, purchase_amount )
  values( 1, round( 100.99/2, 2 ));
```

or

```
insert into spend_amount( record_no, purchase_amount )
  values( 1, trunc( 100.99/2, 2 ));
```